# optionall adding text at the end of an angular expression

Tags: angularjs, expression, angularjs-1.5

I have an expression that's pull data from a controller, the number of pages of a book.

If the data exists, I want to print "X pages", where X is the value. Otherwose, I want the HTML paragraph to be blank.

But, I can't get the syntax correct. Below, it always prints out ' pages', even if blank. How do I set up my expression?

```
  <p>{{reviewFormCtrl.book.numPages + ' pages' || "" }}</p>
```

I tried doing ternary operator in the expression, but didn't have lukc

```
 <p>{{(reviewFormCtrl.book.numPages > 0)?{{reviewFormCtrl.book.numPages + ' pages' :"" }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<p ng-if="reviewFormCtrl.book.numPages">{{ reviewFormCtrl.book.numPages }} pages</p>
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as I think it's more readable than @developer033's answer. other answer gives the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the below `code` to achieve what you want:

```
<p>{{ reviewFormCtrl.book.numPages ? reviewFormCtrl.book.numPages + ' pages' : "" }}</p>
```

Comment: this works. i believe the other answer is a bit more elegant / readable.

Comment: Can be, I did this way because I follow what you actually have. It can be done in a lot of ways..